# Generic Top Level Domains: are they catching on yet at all?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name

Is anyone buying ".club", ".today", ".cool" etc? Is there any way of finding out statistics to watch when one of these begins to approach mainstream use rather than just being a novelty as they most likely are for now?

One other related question: are companies having to buy all these up to keep others from snagging them? For example, does Microsoft own Microsoft.zone and Microsoft.cash and on and on?

Comment: @Jan helped me identify what I was talking about. Originally I called it a "Domain Name Suffix" in the question title because I didn't know what they were called.

Answer (score 0):

They are called TLDs (Top Level Domains) and the new ones are called "Generic TLDs". I believe that lots of companies are buying domains from these gTLDs - but I have yet to come across someone actually using them in real life.